# Jenkins Warning Plugin 4.68 Pylint 1.9 Python 2.7 Reports and Graphs are Basic/Dated - How to Configure for new style

Tags: jenkins, plugins, graph, warnings, pylint

Simply running pylint against python code base :

pylint --rcfile=pylint.cfg ${FILE_PATH} --msg-template="{path}:{line}: [{msg_id}({symbol}), {obj}] {msg}" >> pylint.log

Output is standard html table , basic graphs, no bells and whistles , radar graphs or otherwise modern as depicted on the Warnings plugin site. How to bring output to this century ?

Comment: The view I'm describing is in the Jenkins UI, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Warnings Plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin

Comment: the parser in the post-build is PyLint